# Python while loop execution speed up

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, numba

Update: Does anyone know how to write the While loop below in Cython? I need it to be very fast.  I'm not experienced with Cython but from what I can gather I would need to replace the NumPy calls with code that can be compiled in C.

---

Is there a way to make the following code much faster, for example, by replacing the NumPy functions so that Numba can compile the while loop in nopython mode?  The input variables, (rows, cols), are 1D lists/arrays of integers.

```
import numpy as np

def cluster(rows, cols):
    member_sets = []
    centroids = []
    while cols.any():
        un, coun = np.unique(cols, return_counts=True)
        centroid = un[np.argmax(coun)]
        centroids.append(centroid)
        member_set = rows[cols == centroid]
        member_sets.append(member_set)
        rows = rows[np.in1d(cols, member_set, invert=True)]
        cols = cols[np.in1d(cols, member_set, invert=True)]
        cols = cols[np.in1d(rows, member_set, invert=True)]
        rows = rows[np.in1d(rows, member_set, invert=True)]
    return member_sets, centroids
```

One can benchmark on the following dataset:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(1000, random_state=1)
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(metric='euclidean', radius=3)
nbrs.fit(X)
adj_mat = nbrs.radius_neighbors_graph(X)
rows = adj_mat.nonzero()[0]
cols = adj_mat.nonzero()[1]
```

What I am getting on my laptop:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("cluster(rows, cols)", globals=globals(), number=100)
Output: 12.490656665991992
```

Is it possible to increase the speed by an order of magnitude (< 1 sec) or better?

Here are the results from profiling, with a dataset size of 10,000.  It looks like the most expensive NumPy call is to argsort.

```
   import cProfile

   cProfile.run('m,c = cluster(rows, cols)')
         1423 function calls in 78.965 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.214    1.214   78.965   78.965 <ipython-input-1-44e1e663f585>:3(cluster)
        1    0.000    0.000   78.965   78.965 <string>:1(<module>)
       14    0.000    0.000    0.064    0.005 _methods.py:37(_any)
       49    1.161    0.024   76.805    1.567 arraysetops.py:113(unique)
       49   11.946    0.244   75.644    1.544 arraysetops.py:250(_unique1d)
       52    0.879    0.017   68.924    1.325 arraysetops.py:385(in1d)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.014    0.001 fromnumeric.py:1487(nonzero)
       16    0.000    0.000    3.447    0.215 fromnumeric.py:2053(cumsum)
       42    0.000    0.000    3.461    0.082 fromnumeric.py:55(_wrapfunc)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:910(argmax)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:1843(diff)
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:150(ones)
      104    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:463(asarray)
      111    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:534(asanyarray)
        1    0.000    0.000   78.965   78.965 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       42    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
      138    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
      215    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
       96    0.112    0.001    0.112    0.001 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.copyto}
       70    0.056    0.001    0.056    0.001 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
       14    0.000    0.000    0.064    0.005 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       26    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'argmax' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       34   51.303    1.509   51.303    1.509 {method 'argsort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       16    3.447    0.215    3.447    0.215 {method 'cumsum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       49    0.493    0.010    0.493    0.010 {method 'flatten' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       13    0.013    0.001    0.013    0.001 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
      104    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       14    0.064    0.005    0.064    0.005 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
       31    8.276    0.267    8.276    0.267 {method 'sort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Comment: Why do you think that 12,5 seconds is not acceptable? If it does the job… Are you over optimizing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that's just for benchmarking.  I am using the function for input rows/cols of len > 20,000,000, where the function takes hours to execute once.

Comment: You seem to be making the same `in1d` calls twice inside the loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Repeatedly find the highest-degree node in a graph, delete it, and repeat with the remaining subgraph?

Comment: or... no, delete its *neighbors*?

Comment: It's a greedy clustering algorithm.  It is equivalent to the following: take a distance matrix, find the column (centroid) with the largest number of components less than some distance cutoff, store the indices of those components in a list (members), remove every column and row with those indices from the distance matrix, and repeat the above for the smaller distance matrix, until there is no distance matrix remaining.  The resulting clusters share no members. The posted implementation gives the same results but can work much faster than using the full distance matrix.  But, it's still slow.

Comment: What is `member`? It doesn't look like the code posted here would actually work... Also, have you profiled it to see which Numpy function is using most time?

Comment: @DavidW, Thanks for the suggestion.  You were right, there was a code typo (that's what I get by typing it from memory...).  I fixed the typo and profiled the code.  Looks like the most expensive function is argsort.  Any suggestions on how to get this working in Cython or Numba?  Would really like to C compile this.

Comment: @NickPolizzi You're not going to write a better version of argsort in Cython/Numba. You should see if you can change your algorithm to avoid `argsort` - I think it's probably in `unique`. Maybe try sorting `cols` once at the start, and then seeing if you can write/find a faster version of `unique` that works on sorted arrays